# What's Wrong with Word 2013 Print Layout View

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Could of days ago, I got MS Office 2013 final version. Everything is fine except one problem.

I use Word in Print Layout View. When I press enter to create new line, a stupid horizontal line appears. It appears after pressing enter each time.

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any way to remove that unwanted line. This line appears like margin line. And it doesn't appear in print actually. But I feel too much uncomfortable while working on it.

Look at the image below:
[image: Word Text Boundaries Problem]

This stupid lines appear if text boundary option is selected :(

By the way, I'm not a new user at all. I provide solution to many problems through my blog. But this time, I've been puzzled. Is there anybody to help me out please?

Comment: Did you applt the 1.2gb of updates to the product after installing it?

Comment: Even after you apply this Microsoft Update will have even more updates for you.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42017

Comment: Actually it's the latest version. And this problem was also present in the trial versions too. I think this is just a setting of new Word. Sometimes Microsoft provide unusual settings which are of no use. By the way, have u understood my problem actually?

Comment: I have suggested applying updates because sometimes microsoft releases patches to fix problems like this.

Comment: If File->Options->Advanced->Show Document Content->Show text boundaries is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: I didn't mean that! :) I want text boundaries. But don't want the lines appear after pressing enter each time. Look at the picture I shared in post.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

Sorry - missed the "text boundary option" bit :-) But AFAIK this is not easily fixed. Although the problem relates to documents that have been created in Word 2013 mode, so, e.g., a document created in Word 2010 will probably display the way you want, and if you can save a new file in Word 2010 mode that may be OK, but I don't think there is a simple way to take a Word 2013 mode document and revert it to Word 2010 mode.

AFAICS here, this particular issue comes down to a single setting in the XML - specifically, in the settings.xml part, when you save in Word 2013 mode, there is a  w:compat/w:compatSetting element with w:val = '15'. If you change that to '14' the boundaries should display as they used to. But I don't see an option to do /just that one thing/ in the Word User Interface, and of course to do it in the XML you either have to mess around looking inside the .docx or save as a Word flat OPC format file and fix the value in there.